# Inferring A given C and chain ABC

Tags: probability, causality

We have a claimed causal chain $A\to B\to C$. We know that $P(C) < 0.01$ and we know that $P(B|A) > 0.9$ and $P(C|B) > 0.9,$ how can we find $P(A)?$

We might lack information here but can we approximate it?

Comment: Causality is not a necessary condition to attempt this problem. Are you aware of how Bayes' rule relates total and conditional probabilities? If you use Bayes you can either solve this or prove that it's unsolvable with the information given.

Comment: yes I know Bayes and conditional probability but I don't think it's easily solvable with basic laws

Comment: I am treating this like a https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study problem. Maybe it is? Anyway, the answer doesn't depend on whether it's easily or difficultly solved. It's either solvable or not, and if not you can pinpoint what one or two features are missing to enable solving it.

Comment: $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C $ is not equivalent to $A \subset B \subset C$, correct? Does it imply anything else than $P(B \mid A) \approx 1$ and $P(C\mid B) \approx 1$ ? From the information provided, it is impossible to establish a lower bound for $A$ other than 0.

Comment: Consider the simplified problem: , $P(B\mid A ) > 0.9$, $P(B) < 0.01$. Then $P(B) = P(A)P(B\mid A)+ P(A^c)P(B\mid A^c)$ and so $P(A) = \frac{P(B) - P(A^c)P(B\mid A^c)}{P(B\mid A)} < \frac{0.01 - P(B\mid A^c)}{0.9}$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing because of the lack of distinction between events and random variables. I'll assume that $A, B, C$ are Bernoulli random variables, and that all the probabilities concern success events like $P(C=1)<0.01$, and so on.

With this interpretation, we can use the information you gave to obtain a statement on $P(A=1)$. Clearly, if $A=1$, the event $C=1$ if very likely because $P(B=1\mid A=1) > 0.9$, and $P(C=1 \mid B=1) > 0.9$, meaning that $P(C=1 \mid A=1) > 0.9^2$.

Assuming the most extreme case of $P(C=1 \mid A=0) = 0$, we would still need $P(A=1) < \frac{0.01}{0.9^2}$ to be able to achieve $P(C=1) < 0.01$ (this is a necessary, not a sufficient criterion).
If $P(C=1 \mid A=0)$ was greater than $0$, $P(A=1)$ would have to be even lower.